# Model freezes and becomes very laggy after long run time

Tags: anylogic

I am referencing Benjamin Schumann's tutorial guide on building a self-configuring model https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casVdmKC-S0 and also downloaded the resource files to work on. However, I realize that the model animation starts to freeze after a long run time (eg. 30,000 secs) [image: Screenshot of freeze screen] and at this point, the model also becomes very laggy in response to clicks. I have built my model with reference to the key concepts taught in the video and also faces the same issue now. What are the causes of these and how can it be rectified? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for working on this ;)

Now it looks like you are creating thousands of products (top left corner) but only a few hundred have completed their cycle and been destroyed in the sink.

So my first guess is: you have too many product agents that are all being rendered on top of each other (having 1000s of agents is fine typically, but drawing them all can slow things down).

So adjust your model in 2 ways:

- either change the logic so you never have too many products around
- or hide products that are waiting or stuck somewhere

Comment: Thank you so much Benjamin! Your solution helped solve the issue. It was really due to overwhelming numbers of products being generated and not utilized that is slowing the model. Really appreciate your videos too! Highly recommend your tutorial videos as they really helped me pick up on Anylogic :) Thumbs up!